# Trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 with NodeJS, i am using the "mssql" package, i dont have answer here is my code

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var opciones = {
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypass',
  server: 'myserver',
  database: 'mydatabase',
  options: {
      encrypt: true
  }
  };
  sql.connect(opciones,function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log("CONEXIÓN EXITOSA");
    }
  });
```

the name of that js is "cnSQL.js", when i execute on cmd "node cnSQL" I dont have answer.

Comment: did you setup the configuration file with the appropriate connection information?

Comment: Yes, i do, when i change the server i got error, but when i put a incorrect user i dont have error message.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Timeout error, i think it's correct, because that server dont exist, but when i put the correct server i dont have message, i think i have to get the "CONEXIÓN EXITOSA" message on console.

Comment: Could you try to write your sql.connect in this format sql.connect("mssql://username:password@localhost/database").then(function() ?

Comment: i just tried, and i got the same problem, nothing,

Comment: var sql = require('mssql');
sql.connect("mssql://myuser:mypass@myserver/mydatabase").then(function(){
  new sql.Request().query('select * from PRUEBA').then(function(recordset) {
  console.dir(recordset);
 }).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

Tested the code as above with my local DB instance.
The code is actually correct.

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var opciones = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'mypass',
  server: '127.0.0.1',
  database: 'mydb',
  options: {
      encrypt: true
  }
  };
  sql.connect(opciones,function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log("CONEXIÓN EXITOSA");
    }
  });
```

I have managed to get the 'Connexion Exitosa' message.
In order to further debug your issue, attempt the following:

With the username you are trying to login with (In my case 'sa')

Open SQL Server Management Studio and attempt to put in the connection information as above. Click login, does that work?

If not:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the SQL Server Instance you are trying to connect to from NodeJS
3. Right click on the instance of your SQL server and click properties
4. Click security and ensure that the "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" radio button is selected.
5. When done click OK
6. On the left hand navigation expand the Node "Security"
7. Expand Logins
8. Find your user and ensure it is enabled and that the password you selected reflects the password within your NodeJS app.

If so:

Amend all the information within the code to reflect exactly the credentials used to login

Special Note: '.' will not represent localhost here. Use 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Furthermore, if the SQL server instance you are trying to connect to is not hosted locally. Ensure that the machine it is hosted on accepts connections on port 1433 (by default for SQL Server).

Hope it helps!